# ClamAV installation issue

Tags: ansible, rhel7, epel

Ansilbe role [ansible-role-clamav](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-clamav)

May I know if there are any changes in the ClamAV package names?

OS - RHEL Server release 7.7 (Mapio)

Ansible version - 2.8.2

Its installation is failing with the below error.

```
TASK [ansible-role-clamav : Install ClamAV packages]
fatal: [base-image]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "No package matching 'clamav-server' found available, installed or updated", "rc": 126, "results": ["No package matching 'clamav-server' found available, installed or updated"]}[0m
```

Comment: Please provide more informations (e.g. Server-OS, Ansible version)

Comment: Have you tried the installation manually? It seems to me that the server is unable to connect to internet to search for packages

Comment: Server has internet connectivity and manages to install the other packages but it fails to install the clamav-server because it doesn't exist. It was there in epel repository upto last week.

Comment: that's the issue...I will always test a manual installation, check the epel repo's for the corresponding packages...You can try different mirrors for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the packages have changed based on this.

https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/c/

New packages: [ 'clamav', 'clamav-data', 'clamav-devel', 'clamav-filesystem', 'clamav-lib', 'clamav-milter', 'clamav-update', 'clamav-unofficial-sigs', 'clamd']